# PHP search script for multiple words

Tags: php, search, words

I have the following issue:

I can't search multiple words.

I have a search engine who search just the full string:

PHP Code:

---

```
function ft_search_sidebar() {
  $sidebar[] = array(
    "id" => "search_1",
    "content" => '<div class="section">
        <h2>'.t('Search files &amp; folders').'</h2>
        <form action="" method="post" id="searchform">
            <div>
                <input type="text" name="q" id="q" size="16" value="'.$_REQUEST['q'].'" />
                <input type="button" id="dosearch" value="'.t('Search').'" />
            </div>
            <div id="searchoptions">
                <input type="checkbox" name="type" id="type" checked="checked" /> <label for="type">'.t('Search only this folder and below').'</label>
            </div>
            <div id="searchresults"></div>
        </form>
    </div>'
  );
  return $sidebar;
}


function ft_search_ajax($act) {
  if ($act = '%search%') {
    $new = array();
    $ret = "";
    $q = $_POST['q'];
    $type = $_POST['type'];
    if (!empty($q)) {
        if ($type == "true") {
            $list = _ft_search_find_files(ft_get_dir(), $q);
        } else {
            $list = _ft_search_find_files(ft_get_root(), $q);
        }
```

Can someone help me?

Grtz

Answer (score 0):

You will need to either develop a search engine which is capable of multi keyword search or simply extract out all the keywords from the search string and then use the search engine multiple times for each keyword. Like this:

```
$q = $_POST['q'];
$type = $_POST['type'];
if (!empty($q)) {
    if(strpos(trim($q),' ') > 0)
    {
         $array = explode(' ',trim($q));
         foreach($array as $key=>$value)
         {
             //process search multiple times for different values of $value
         }
    }
    else
    {
         if ($type == "true")
         {
             $list = _ft_search_find_files(ft_get_dir(), $q);
         }
         else
         {
             $list = _ft_search_find_files(ft_get_root(), $q);
         }
    }
```